# Trying to display posts by authors in with specific user meta

Tags: custom-post-types, wpdb, user-meta

Ok here's the solution:

```
<?php 
$wp_user_search1 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'NM',
));
$listers1 = $wp_user_search1->get_results();

$lister_ids1 = array();
foreach($listers1 as $lister1) {
    $lister_ids1[] = $lister1->ID;
}

$ids1 = implode(',', $lister_ids1);

$wp_user_search2 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'TX',
));
$listers2 = $wp_user_search2->get_results();

$lister_ids2 = array();
foreach($listers2 as $lister2) {
    $lister_ids2[] = $lister2->ID;
}

$ids2 = implode(',', $lister_ids2);

$wp_user_search3 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'OK',
));
$listers3 = $wp_user_search3->get_results();

$lister_ids3 = array();
foreach($listers3 as $lister3) {
    $lister_ids3[] = $lister3->ID;
}

$ids3 = implode(',', $lister_ids3);

$wp_user_search4 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'TX',
));
$listers4 = $wp_user_search4->get_results();

$lister_ids4 = array();
foreach($listers4 as $lister4) {
    $lister_ids4[] = $lister4->ID;
}

$ids4 = implode(',', $lister_ids4);

$wp_user_search5 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'TX',
));
$listers5 = $wp_user_search5->get_results();

$lister_ids5 = array();
foreach($listers5 as $lister5) {
    $lister_ids5[] = $lister5->ID;
}

$ids5 = implode(',', $lister_ids5);

$wp_user_search6 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'TX',
));
$listers6 = $wp_user_search6->get_results();

$lister_ids6 = array();
foreach($listers6 as $lister6) {
    $lister_ids6[] = $lister6->ID;
}

$ids6 = implode(',', $lister_ids6);

$ids = $ids1.",". $ids2.",". $ids3.",". $ids4.",". $ids5.",". $ids6;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'listing',
'author' => $ids,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged
);

$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();?>
```

Comment: I have it working for one meta value, but need it for multiple.

Comment: I had to concatenate all the returned variables for each meta value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$args` is a variable and as such should not be wrapped in quotes in the arguments array of `query_posts()`. Now that should be what's causing the whole thing to fail.

That being said, there are a few more flaws I see in your code:

- I'd recommend using the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead of `query_posts()` ([why is that?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts))
- While it works, I'd not use `$args` as a variable name unless it's actually all the arguments to a wp function. Just to stick to consistent syntax.
- Why are you calling `global $query_string;` if you're not using it in the query itsself?

You're good till the `foreach` loop has finished. The whole thing should look something like this:

```
$your_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'state' , 
    'meta_value' => 'NM'
    ));
$listers = $your_user_search->get_results();
$lister_ids = array();
foreach($listers as $lister) {
    $lister_ids[] = $lister->ID;
}
// query arguments
$authors = implode(',', $lister_ids);
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'author' => $authors,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
// query for posts
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop through found posts
while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
    // inside of loop, echo markup and post content here
endwhile;
// pagination, with check for WP-PageNavi plugin
if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $your_query ) );
} elseif ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link() ) {
    // optional: echo markup around links
    next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older Entries', $your_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries &raquo;' );
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // reset post data, important!
```

Comment: although this helps clean up my loop (can't get the pagination to work though) the wpdb statement is not drawing any of the author id's

Comment: @eteich Seeing now that you edited your code. Why? The `$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query(...)` bit was totally fine!

Comment: @eteich Also see the arguments passed to either `wp_pagenavi()` or `next_post_link()`. The above should now pretty much be copy&paste ready...

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 of your code has a typo - "litsers" instead of "listers" (line 9).

Comment: Fixed it, but I still am getting no output.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is right but just one thing wrong, your are selecting `user_id` and later you try to access `id` which is not the the id of the user, but the id of the meta entry.

try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'state'
    AND meta_value = 'NM'";
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$lister_ids = implode(',', $author_ids);
$listq = new WP_Query(array( 
    'post_type' => 'listing', 
    'author' => $lister_ids , 
    'posts_per_page' => '10' ,  
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
    )
);
if ( $listq->have_posts() ) : while ( $listq->have_posts() ) : $listq->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: plugged that in an it didn't work for me.

Comment: I would love to use this method, because I could do all the searching in one fell swoop, but I cannot get the outputted sql formatted to just the user id's seperated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the entire fix... It's a lot of server load, but it works for the implementation that was already in place.

Discovers users by state for a certain zone and displays all posts in a table.

```
<?php 
$wp_user_search1 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'TN',
));
$listers1 = $wp_user_search1->get_results();

$lister_ids1 = array();
foreach($listers1 as $lister1) {
    $lister_ids1[] = $lister1->ID;
}

$ids1 = implode(',', $lister_ids1);

$wp_user_search2 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'NC',
));
$listers2 = $wp_user_search2->get_results();

$lister_ids2 = array();
foreach($listers2 as $lister2) {
    $lister_ids2[] = $lister2->ID;
}

$ids2 = implode(',', $lister_ids2);

$wp_user_search3 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'SC',
));
$listers3 = $wp_user_search3->get_results();

$lister_ids3 = array();
foreach($listers3 as $lister3) {
    $lister_ids3[] = $lister3->ID;
}

$ids3 = implode(',', $lister_ids3);

$wp_user_search4 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'AL',
));
$listers4 = $wp_user_search4->get_results();

$lister_ids4 = array();
foreach($listers4 as $lister4) {
    $lister_ids4[] = $lister4->ID;
}

$ids4 = implode(',', $lister_ids4);

$wp_user_search5 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'GA',
));
$listers5 = $wp_user_search5->get_results();

$lister_ids5 = array();
foreach($listers5 as $lister5) {
    $lister_ids5[] = $lister5->ID;
}

$ids5 = implode(',', $lister_ids5);

$wp_user_search6 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers6 = $wp_user_search6->get_results();

$lister_ids6 = array();
foreach($listers6 as $lister6) {
    $lister_ids6[] = $lister6->ID;
}

$ids6 = implode(',', $lister_ids6);

$wp_user_search7 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers7 = $wp_user_search7->get_results();

$lister_ids7 = array();
foreach($listers7 as $lister7) {
    $lister_ids7[] = $lister7->ID;
}

$ids7 = implode(',', $lister_ids7);

$wp_user_search8 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers8 = $wp_user_search8->get_results();

$lister_ids8 = array();
foreach($listers8 as $lister8) {
    $lister_ids8[] = $lister8->ID;
}

$ids8 = implode(',', $lister_ids8);

$wp_user_search9 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers9 = $wp_user_search9->get_results();

$lister_ids9 = array();
foreach($listers9 as $lister9) {
    $lister_ids9[] = $lister9->ID;
}

$ids9 = implode(',', $lister_ids9);

$wp_user_search10 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers10 = $wp_user_search10->get_results();

$lister_ids10 = array();
foreach($listers10 as $lister10) {
    $lister_ids10[] = $lister10->ID;
}

$ids10 = implode(',', $lister_ids10);

$wp_user_search11 = new WP_User_Query( array(
'meta_key' => 'state' , 
'meta_value' => 'FL',
));
$listers11 = $wp_user_search11->get_results();

$lister_ids11 = array();
foreach($listers11 as $lister11) {
    $lister_ids11[] = $lister11->ID;
}

$ids11 = implode(',', $lister_ids11);

$ids = $ids1.",". $ids2.",". $ids3.",". $ids4.",". $ids5.",". $ids6.",". $ids7.",". $ids8.",". $ids9.",". $ids10.",". $ids11;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'listing',
'author' => $ids,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged
);

$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();?>

<?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
<tr>
    <td class="td50 light"><div class="front_img"><a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?php postimage('thumbnail'); ?></a></div></td>
    <td class="td357 light"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a></td>
    <td class="td40 light"><?php the_field( 'package_size' ); ?></td>
    <td class="td40 light"><?php the_field( 'product_condition' ); ?></td>
    <td class="td40 light"><?php the_field( 'product_quantity' ); ?></td>
    <td class="td40 light">$<?php the_field( 'asking_price' ); ?><br />Per&nbsp;<?php the_field( 'package_quantity' ); ?></td>
    <td class="td40 light">

        <?php if (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'WA') { ?>1
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'OR') { ?>1
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'ID') { ?>1
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'AZ') { ?>2
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'CA') { ?>2
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NV') { ?>2
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'UT') { ?>2
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MT') { ?>3
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'WY') { ?>3
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'ND') { ?>3
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'SD') { ?>3
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'CO') { ?>4
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NE') { ?>4
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'KS') { ?>4
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'IA') { ?>4
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MO') { ?>4
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NM') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'TX') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'OK') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'AR') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MS') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'LA') { ?>5
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MN') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'WI') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'IL') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'IN') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MI') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'OH') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'KY') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'WV') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'VA') { ?>6
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'TN') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NC') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'SC') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'AL') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'GA') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'FL') { ?>7
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'PA') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NY') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'ME') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'VT') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NH') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MA') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'RI') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'CT') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'NJ') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'DE') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'MD') { ?>8
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'AK') { ?>9
        <?php } elseif (get_the_author_meta('state') == 'HI') { ?>9
        <?php } else { ?>&nbsp;<?php } ?>

    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</table>
<div id="paginav">
<div class="alignright">
<?php if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
      wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $your_query ) );
      }
      elseif ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link() )
 previous_posts_link( 'Previous &raquo;' );

 next_posts_link( '&laquo; Next', $your_query->max_num_pages );
?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```